# Is there a better or more compact way of adding items in treeview using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I am using the following code to add nodes in a treeview. Is there a better or more compact way of doing this by using LINQ?

```
foreach (Plan plan in this.IncomingPlan.Plans)
{
    foreach (Document doc in plan.Documents.Where(d => d.Name.Equals(this.DocumentName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    {
        foreach (Author author in doc.Authors)
        {
            TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode()
            {
                Text = author.Name,
                Type = NodeType.ParentNode,
                Tag = author
            };

            foreach (Book book in author.Books)
            {
                treeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode()
                {                    
                    Text = book.Name,
                    Type = NodeType.ChildNode,
                    Tag = book
                });
            }

            this.treeView.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this more maintainable and more compact by utilizing LINQ here.  I'm not sure what `TreeNode` is in your code, I'm guessing you derived from a WinForms `TreeNode`.

I'd argue that the node's `Type` is unnecessary.  You can easily determine that if you look at its `Level`.  Level `0` indicates it is at the root of the tree, otherwise it is greater than 0.

Unfortunately there's no nice way to add a range of nodes to another.  You could only add arrays of the nodes.  Using a loop would be the best option.

Here, I would flatten the nested loops as far as I can then loop through to add them to the tree.  To compact it even more, create a factory method to create the nodes.  Even more useful if you have a lot of properties to set.

```
// create the node for the item
static TreeNode CreateNode<T>(T item, Func<T, string> textSelector)
{
    return new TreeNode { Text = textSelector(item), Tag = item };
}

var authors =
    from plan in this.IncomingPlan.Plans
    from doc in plan.Documents
    where doc.Name.Equals(this.DocumentName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    from author in doc.Authors
    select author;

foreach (var author in authors)
{
    var authorNode = CreateNode(author, a => a.Name);

    foreach (var book in author.Books)
    {
        authorNode.Nodes.Add(CreateNode(book, b => b.Name));
    }

    treeView.Nodes.Add(authorNode);
}
```

Comment: Might be handy to write an extension method on TreeNodeCollection which allows you to add an IEnumerable<TreeNode>. It would still loop under the hood but that detail would be abstracted from you :)

Comment: I'd also a method BookToTreeNode(Book b) which could be used in a linq projection -- authorNode.Nodes.Add(author.Books.Select(BookToTreeNode))

Comment: I thought about that at first but decided it is better to not create extension methods for that purpose.  It's too bad not all collections support adding ranges (`IEnumerable<T>` in particular) of items but I don't see the compelling need to write an extension method to do so either as it's not something that is needed too often.

Answer (score 4):

Looks perfectly fine to me. That's the first time I've looked at your code and I was able to see quickly what it does.

There is no need to overly-compact things if it is going to make it a pain for someone else to understand in future.

Comment: **four** nested foreach loops doesn't look that great! This is a good example of the arrowhead anti-pattern

Comment: @MattDavey, I was also concerned about the nested loops that's why I asked the question :)